# Redirect updates of entity from setter methods to go through service method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to redirect all updates of an entity to go through service method. So for example
if I have someEntity.setSomeAttribute("Value") it will execute an update method because of the ORM(hibernate). But I want that update and all others updates that come from calling a setter method to go through a method in my SomeEntityService.
In order to do that I implemented a PreUpdateEventListener in order to catch all the updates for that entity.

```
public class SomeEntityPreUpdateEventListener implements PreUpdateEventListener {

    private final SomeEntityService someEntityService;

    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent preUpdateEvent) {

        final Object entity = preUpdateEvent.getEntity();
        if (entity instanceof SomeEntity) {
            final SomeEntity someEntity = (SomeEntity) entity;
            if (!someEntity.isServiceUpdate()) {
                System.out.println("SomeEntity is not updated from service. Calling service  method");
                someEntityService.updateSomeEntity(someEntity);

                System.out.println("Finished service method");
                return true;
            }
            System.out.println("Update from service method");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I added a boolean serviceUpdate in the SomeEntity and I set it to true in the updateSomeEntity.

```
public SomeEntity updateSomeEntity(@NotNull SomeEntity item) {
    item.setServiceUpdate(true);
    SomeEntity createdItem = crudRepository.save(item);
    this.entityManager.flush();
    this.entityManager.refresh(createdItem);
    return createdItem;
}
```

So I expect this to update the entity and again the listener to be called where now `isServiceUpdate` is true so it wouldn't veto the update.
But somehow `updateSomeEntity` does 2 updates and in both cases `isServiceUpdate` is true and I get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null`. I assume that `entityManager.flush()`
does the previous update that I want to forbid(but now has isServiceUpdate=true).

Is there any way to achieve calling a setter that will update the entity always to go through service method ?

Tried with evicting the organization, read about entity listeners but somehow I don't have idea how to do this with event listener. `